# Excel Macro not going in the order it's supposed to

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have written a macro which is supposed to run an add-in on each worksheet.
The Add-in is a Sage specific Add-in. I'm sure the sendkeys should work with whatever sendkeys I put in?
However, it runs my test "add text" on all the sheets, goes back to the original active sheet, and then runs the add-in as many times as the count of sheets - all on the active sheet. I also need to add something so that it skips the hidden worksheets...?
Please help.

```
Sub CountSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet

Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets



 ws.Activate
                Application.SendKeys "%XRV%O", True
                Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
                ws.Cells(1, 1) = "Created by Yo Castle 7 "
                Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

Next


starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active


End Sub
```

Comment: No error: it runs my test "add text" on all the sheets, goes back to the original active sheet, and then runs the add-in as many times as the count of sheets - all on the active sheet

Comment: i need to know why my macro is not working as i expected. What did I do wrong?

Comment: the macro is supposed to run the sendkeys on a worksheet, then go to the next active worksheet, run the sendkeys again, then go to the next active worksheet, and run the sendkeys again. My workbook has about 50 worksheets where i must run the sendkeys. Does this make sense?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include what the send keys are meant to do? I don't have menu or tab that matches `ALT`+`X` so I can't test it properly.

Comment: Also, are you sure the wait statement is actually waiting? try `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))` instead or increase the wait time to test.

Comment: try also splitting the sendkeys into 3 or 4 separate keystrokes, perhaps with a "false" wait value on the last one.

Answer (score 1):

To only run the marco on the visible sheets you can add an [`IF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) just after you start your loop. This will then test if the [`Visible`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible) property is true otherwise, skip to the next one.

So your code becomes:

```
Sub CountSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet

Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Visible = true Then

 ws.Activate
                Application.SendKeys "%XRV%O", True
                Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
                ws.Cells(1, 1) = "Created by Yo Castle 7 "
                Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
End If

Next


starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active


End Sub
```